# Extract some data from a text file

Tags: python-3.x

I am not so experienced in Python.
I have a “CompilerWarningsAllProtocol.txt” file that contains something like this:
" adm_1 C:\Work\CompilerWarnings\adm_1.h type:warning Reason:wunused
adm_2 E:\Work\CompilerWarnings\adm_basic.h type:warning Reason:undeclared variable
adm_X C:\Work\CompilerWarnings\adm_X.h type:warning Reason: Unknown ID"

How can I extract these three paths(C:..., E:..., C:...) from the txt file and to fill an Excel column named “Affected Item”.?
Can I do it with re.findall or re.search methods?

For now the script is checkling if in my location exists the input txt file and confirms it. After that it creates the blank excel file with headers, but I don't know how to populate the excel file with these paths written in column " Affected Item" let's say.

thanks for help. I will copy-paste the code:

```
import os
import os.path
import re
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl
from jira import JIRA
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Print error message if no "CompilerWarningsAllProtocol.txt" file exists in the folder
inputpath = 'D:\Work\Python\CompilerWarnings\Python_CompilerWarnings\CompilerWarningsAllProtocol.txt'
if os.path.isfile(inputpath) and os.access(inputpath, os.R_OK):
print(" 'CompilerWarningsAllProtocol.txt' exists and is readable")
else:
    print("Either the file is missing or not readable")

# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('CompilerWarningsFresh.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Results')

# Widen correspondingly the columns.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)
worksheet.set_column('B:AZ', 45)

# Create the headers
headers=('Module','Affected Item', 'Issue', 'Class of Issue', 'Issue Root Cause', 'Type of Issue', 
'Source of Issue', 'Test sequence', 'Current Issue appearances in module')
# Create the bold headers and font size
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'black',})
format1.set_font_size(14)
format1.set_border()
row=col=0
for item in (headers):
    worksheet.write(row, col, item, format1)
    col += 1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Provide the file

Comment: You *could* just use csv for ease-of-use. And if each new path is on a new line you could just use the built-in [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function and iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @dantechguy that csv is probably easier (and more light weight) than writing a real xlsx file, but if you want to stick to Excel format, the code below will work. Also, based on the code you've provided, you don't need to import `openpyxl`, `jira`, `pandas` or `numpy`.

The regex here matches full paths with any drive letter A-Z, followed by "type:warning". If you don't need to check for the warning and simply want to get every path in the file, you can delete everything in the regex after `S+`. And if you know you'll only ever want drives C and E, just change `A-Z` to `CE`.

```
warningPathRegex = r"[A-Z]:\\\S+(?=\s*type:warning)"
compilerWarningFile = r"D:\Work\Python\CompilerWarnings\Python_CompilerWarnings\CompilerWarningsAllProtocol.txt"

warningPaths = []

with open(compilerWarningFile, 'r') as f:
  fullWarningFile = f.read()
  warningPaths = re.findall(warningPathRegex, fullWarningFile)

# ... open Excel file, then before workbook.close():

pathColumn = 1 # Affected item

for num, warningPath in enumerate(warningPaths):
  worksheet.write(num + 1, pathColumn, warningPath) # num + 1 to skip header row
```